# Firefox Page Inspector API to Max/msp

Tags: firefox, safari-web-inspector, max-msp-jitter

this is my first question here so please don't be too judging. I did a fast search but couldn't find anything helpful.
How do i access to the page inspector api on firefox? I'm aiming to connect the page inspector to Max/msp in order to make sounds based on DOM events like clicks etc. etc. As far as I understand Max is able to read file from Internet, but I still need to make clear this point as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question (and my apologies, I see that it was asked some time ago):

- you access all developer tools in Firefox via the "Firefox -> Web Developer" (Win) or "Tools -> Web Developer" (Mac) menu. The "Inspector" option is the closest thing to the Page Inspector you are asking about
- the Inspector (and Web Developer tools in general) are essential for developing web applications, but they will not provide the functionality you are trying to create. You will need to build a web application in Javascript and — to 'speak' with Max — incorporate a library that communicates using UDP datagrams or, better, OSC messages (which are a specific format of UDP datagram.) Check npmjs.com, there are modules there for everything! There is one called "osc-js", by andreasdz, that probably does what you need
- on the Max side, you'll need to use a component called "udpreceive" to pick up and use the messages you're sending from Firefox.

I've found that OSC networks can be very finicky… but once you get everything working, they are enormously powerful. Good luck!